# Unexpected socket connection from 0.0.0.0:32772

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

```
int SocketDebugger::Init(unsigned short p)
{
    if (m_state != dsDisconnect)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (PISocket::Startup()) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    m_port = p;
    m_debug_socket = PISocket::Socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (m_debug_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        Log(LEVEL_PYDEBUGGER, "GetLastError: %d", PISocket::Errno());
        return -2;
    }

    sockaddr_in local;
    memset(&local, 0, sizeof(local));
    local.sin_family = PF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(m_port);

    int ret = PISocket::Bind(m_debug_socket, (sockaddr*)&local);
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        PISocket::Close(m_debug_socket);
        m_debug_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        return -3;
    }

    ret = PISocket::Listen(m_debug_socket, 0);
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        PISocket::Close(m_debug_socket);
        m_debug_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        return -4;
    }

    unsigned long nonblocking = 1;
    ret = PISocket::Ioctl(m_debug_socket, FIONBIO, &nonblocking);
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        PISocket::Close(m_debug_socket);
        m_debug_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        return -5;
    }

    m_state = dsListen;


    unsigned long t = (unsigned long)PITime() + 2000;

    do 
    {
        TryAccept();
    }

    while ((unsigned long)PITime() < t && m_state == dsListen);
    LogInfo("profiler socket init port: %d", port)
    return 0;
}

bool SocketDebugger::TryAccept()
{
    sockaddr_in local;
    //int len = sizeof(local);
    // set non blocking...  

    m_gui_socket = PISocket::Accept(m_debug_socket, (sockaddr*)&local);

    if (m_gui_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {       
        if (PISocket::Errno() == EWOULDBLOCK)
        {   
            return false;
        }
    }

    LogInfo("profiler connected! %s:%d", inet_ntoa(local.sin_addr), local.sin_port);
    m_state = dsConnect;
    m_send_stream.clear();
    m_recv_stream.clear();
    return true;
}
```

I use a remote profiler to connect to my program. I can run this code well in my pc, but somehow in ios, the `TryAccept` is always recieve a connection from `0.0.0.0:32772`. The log is:

```
5   [23:43:04.368]   [UTILS] [INFO] profiler connected! 0.0.0.0:32772
6   [23:43:04.368]   [UTILS] [INFO] profiler socket init port: 7776, 0
```

Why? ps: TryAccept will also be called elsewhere after init

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how this code would have ever worked anywhere. So long as `m_gui_socket` is not equal to `INVALID_SOCKET`, `SocketDebugger::TryAccept` will unconditionally print "profiler connected", and display the contents of an uninitialized `sockaddr_in`. There's nothing in there that actually performs an accept operation!

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. The `TryAccept` will be called else where in a tick function, and first connected address is `0.0.0.0:32772` like always.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with `PISocket::Accept` (or in how it's being used), but you haven't included that in your sample code, so I can't debug that.